# How to make same items height for 2 (different) tables displayed side by side - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two, or more, different tables that are generated by a php loop; I want to make them all the same `<li>` item height for each table with different text:

```html
<div class="table-1">
  <ul>
    <li>short text1</li>
    <li>short text1</li>
    <li>long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 </li>
    <li>short text1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="table-2">
  <ul>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 </li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the `table` html tag? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but you could easily set the height for all li items by adding this to your CSS `li { height: 40px }`

Or see example https://codepen.io/oldskool123/pen/poQqxVK

Comment: I can't use fixed height. The length of the texts is different!

Answer (score 0):

To display the table side by side you have to add some `display:flex` to the list. Refer below code...

HTML:

```
 <div class="d-flex">
<div class="table-1">
  <ul>
    <li>short text1</li>
    <li>short text1</li>
    <li>long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 </li>
    <li>short text1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="table-2">
  <ul>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 </li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
        <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
        <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
    <li>short text2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
  gap:1rem;
}
.table-1,
.table-2{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Border added for visual purpose.
Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: I want each li item of 2 table to be exactly side by side of each other. My question was not about flex 2 Div!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an code example of two tables side by side. All `li` elements have the same heihgt which is the height of the heighst `li` element.
If this is not exactly what you need, please provide better description of your issue ;)

```css
.tables {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    gap: 6px;
}

.table-row {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    gap: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.table-cell {
    background-color: pink;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div class="table">
    <ul class="table-row">
      <li class="table-cell">short text1</li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text1</li>
      <li class="table-cell">long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 long text1 </li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text1</li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <ul class="table-row">
      <li class="table-cell">short text2</li>
      <li class="table-cell">long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 long text2 t2 lon ext2 long text2 t2 lo</li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text2</li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text2</li>
      <li class="table-cell">short text2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Side by side means that short text1 is placed exactly next to short text2, Not that all the columns are placed together.

Comment: With provided markup and without some js hack it is impossible. Organize better your input data and use table.